# Add an Item to a ListBoxControl from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a ListBoxControl in a Form (Form1) and a button under it which I want to show me another form (Form2).

In the Form2 I have a TextBox and a button and I want when I click on this button to Add the current text in the TextBox to the ListBoxControl which is in the other form Form1.

How can I do that ?

***Form 1 :***

[image: FORM 1]

***Form 2 :***

[image: FORM2]

Comment: Is your Keyword form Modal (showdialog) or modeless (show) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard pattern for using dialogs.

On Form2, provide a property for reading the control:

```
public string KeyWord
{
   get { return Textbox1.Text; }
}
```

On Form1, when a Button is clicked:

```
using (Form2 dialog = new Form2())
{
    // init Form2

    var result = dialog.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        sting newKeyWord = dialog.KeyWord;
        // add to listbox
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code on the other form:

```
  Form1 frm;
  if ((frm= (Form1 )IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(Form1))) != null)
  {
      //get the value of the form
      //frm.listboxcontrol.text
  }

  public static Form IsFormAlreadyOpen(Type FormType)
  {
     return Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().FirstOrDefault(OpenForm => OpenForm.GetType() == FormType);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you may create a public method in form1:

```
public SampleMethodName(string Value)
{
  // Write your code to add it the list.
  ListBox1.Add(Value); 
}
```

Now when user open form2, add some text to textbox, and press valider,
You may create an instance of form1.

```
protected void valider_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
  Form1 frm = new Form1();
  frm.SampleMethodName(TextBox.Value);
}
```

Comment: In the form 2 it gives me this error:
'Error 1 'GestionBib.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'AddMotCle' and no extension method 'AddMotCle' accepting a first argument of type 'GestionBib.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: Are you using the public method in form1? If so then it should not generate the exception?

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not want to use the dialog result (as proposed by Henk) but if you want to leave the second form open try the following. I.e. if you want to leave the second form open while adding ListBox items.

Form 1:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormComm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var form2 = new Form2(this);
            form2.Show();
        }

        delegate void AddListBoxItemCallback(string text);
        public void AddListBoxItem(object item)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                AddListBoxItemCallback callback = new AddListBoxItemCallback(AddListBoxItem);
                this.Invoke(callback, new object[] { item });
            }
            else
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(item);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```csharp
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormComm
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private Form1 _form = null;

        public Form2(Form1 form)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this._form = form;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _form.AddListBoxItem(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```